# eMail at one hosting provider, website at another?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, hosting

I have a client that has a php website hosted at network solutions, along with years worth of email and lots of email accounts which he doesn't want to move. I am working on a new website for them that uses asp.net, and sql server, and I would like to host them on my rackspace servers, but don't want to deal with moving the email.

Is it possible from within the network solutions control panel to set up the dns to leave all the email and email accounts where they are, but host the website elsewhere? Any downside to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is setup the MX record in the DNS to continue pointing at the Network Solutions mail server, but change the A record to point to the new web hosts IP address.

Answer (score 4):

If the mail server's hostname is anything other than "www", you shouldn't have to worry.

As Jush Budde pointed out, you just need to change DNS records:

- `www.blah.com A 123.10.20.1` (server at your site)
- `mail.blah.com A 234.20.30.1` (server at network solutions)
- `blah.com MX mail.blah.com`

Maybe you can post your current DNS records (changing the actual Names and IPs)?